# Need Battery Power Solution for Project Exposed to High Temperatures

Tags: batteries

I'm working on a project that requires a 2-5 volt power supply and has the potential to be exposed to temperatures up to 180°C if an error is made by the user. While I understand that damage to the product under these conditions is acceptable, I want to avoid catastrophic failure or any failure that could cause harm or damage.

The plan is to use regular AA alkaline batteries, but I'm concerned about the lack of information regarding the behavior of alkaline batteries at such high temperatures. Does anyone have suggestions for a power source that meets these criteria? The power source must be battery-powered and cannot be plugged in.

Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a search for "high temperature battery" and you will find those designed for things like RFID tags which survive autoclaves.  One example technology  is "Lithium Thionyl Chloride", some datasheets  show 165 C; others claim up o 200 C.

Comment: How much power is needed and for how long?

Comment: An obvious idea is to put the battery outside of the part that gets really hot, if you can.

Comment: It might possibly be easier to fix the design such that the user doesn't make the error you describe.

Comment: You should read the datasheet of the batteries very carefully. If you don't get a datasheet for the batteries check other manufacturers. Use only batteries with a maximum operating temperature higher than 180 °C. The user might be injured if the battery fails. But what if the user replaces the batteries with other ones with a much lower temperature rating?

Comment: Some types of batteries (rechargeable, in particular) are vented so they might discharge some corrosive and noxious materials but they should not explode, at least.

Comment: Without knowing the power requirement or the duration, we're obviously speculating ... but at 180 C there's lots of energy available.  Can you use Peltier?  With that temperature you could run a steam engine!

Comment: Thanks for the comments - the power is fairly low, around 25uA with spikes of 100mA. 2 AA should last 2 years.